# invoking a method that is stored in a dictionary based on an ID using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods, invoke

I have 2 classes in 2 different files.

1. class `InvokeMethod`: receives the byte array (converted to int `actionID` here) from  `Main()` and should invoke the method stored in the dictionary based on the `actionID`. this class should have only generic code so that it can accept any number of methods and objects.
2. Class `ListOfMethods`: adds all the methods from the interface implementation and returns a dictionary with a key, value pair.
3. `Main` method should only have `im.checkID(dataFromString("00 00 00 00"));`
   I have already done the string to byte array conversion(that why i did not put it here).

The class `InvokeMethod` should call the method stored in dictionary based on the `actionID`.

**InvokeMethod**:

```
public class InvokeMethod 
{
    public void checkID(byte[] data)
    {
        int actionID = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);                     
        Console.WriteLine("action id {0}", actionID);
        ListOfMethods GetMethods = new ListOfMethods();
        Dictionary<int, dynamic> methodList = GetMethods.ReturnMethods(actionID);

        //here it should call the method from dictionary based on actionID.

    }
}
```

**ListOfMethods**:

```
public class ListOfMethods
{
    Dictionary<int, dynamic> MethodDictionary = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>();
    Control ControlImplObj = new ControlImpl();
    Type ControlType = typeof(ControlImpl);
    public Dictionary<int, dynamic> ReturnMethods(int actionID)
    {
        var methods = ControlImplObj.GetType().GetMethods();

        foreach (var item in methods.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
        {
            if (item.value.DeclaringType == typeof(ControlImpl))
            {
                MethodDictionary.Add(item.index, item.value);

            }
        }

      return MethodDictionary;
    }
}
```

**Control interface**

```
interface Control
{
    string SetTime();//0
    string Nop();//1
}
```

**Control interface Implementation**

```
public class ControlImpl : Control
{
    public string SetTime()                       
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside SetTime ");
        return null;

    }

   public string Nop()                      
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside Nop ");
        return null;

    }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InvokeMethod im= new InvokeMethod();
        im.checkID(dataFromString("00 00 00 00"));
        im.checkID(dataFromString("00 00 00 01"));
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

Comment: feel free to post as many _new questions_ as you wish but you may want to include all required details in the question. To keep an _open_ question as a forum thread isn't how SO usually works.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I got the solution based on your previous answer. But your answer seems to have been deleted. the thread can now be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you thought that storing methods as `dynamic` would end in being able to call them using regular, compile-time syntax: `x.Method()`, but it's not the case!

When you use reflection you're obtaining metadata. They're not *the methods* but the metadata of these methods which can be used to invoke them.

`Type.GetMethods()` gives you an array of `MethodInfo` and you can invoke a method as follows: `methodInfo.Invoke(instanceOfDeclaringType, new object[] { })` where each index in the given array is an argument of the method. If the method is `static`, you would call the method giving `null` as first argument of `MethodInfo.Invoke`.